# Additions to Esther

Tags: megillat-esther, septuagint

Do any rabbinic sources ( Talmud, geonim, rishonim) talk about the “additions to Esther”found in the Septuagint, regarding its content or it’s authenticity?

Comment: There's a bunch of parallels in Midrashim https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA_%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%AA%D7%A8#%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA

Comment: https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/greek-versions-of-esther/

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34203/what-parts-of-the-septuagint-are-and-are-not-reliable/103815?r=SearchResults#103815