# Why is a Greek Torah Scroll Kosher?

Tags: translation, sefer-torah

I once read that a Greek Sefer Torah is Kosher, is this correct? Is it also correct that Greek is the only language other than Hebrew that a kosher Sefer Torah can be written in?

Comment: See Bavli [Megillah 9b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=11&daf=9b&format=pdf)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48542/5323

Comment: The answers [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18819/5323) are probably useful, though the questions are not duplicate.

Comment: -1: unclear: the question doesn't match its title, and I can't tell which you mean to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the body of your question you ask:

Is a Greek Sefer Torah Kosher?

Is Greek the only language other than Hebrew that a kosher Sefer Torah can be written in?

The answers to these questions are to be found in the [Rambam’s Mishneh Torah, Laws of Tefillin, Mezuzah and Sefer Torah](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/925417/jewish/Tefillin-Mezuzah-and-Sefer-Torah-Chapter-One.htm) Perek 1 Halacha 19:

> Tefillin and mezuzot may be written only in Assyrian script.
>   Permission was granted to write Torah scrolls in Greek as well. That
>   Greek language has, however, been forgotten from the world. It has
>   been confused and has sunk into oblivion. Therefore, at present, all
>   three sacred articles may be written using Assyrian script alone.

The title of your question is:  Why is a Greek Torah Scroll Kosher? 
The reason is given in the [Gemoro Megilla 9b](http://halakhah.com/rst/moed/21%20-%20Megillah%20-%202a-32a.pdf)

> R. SIMEON B. GAMALIEL SAYS THAT BOOKS [OF THE SCRIPTURE] ALSO ARE
>   PERMITTED TO BE WRITTEN ONLY IN GREEK. R. Abbahu said in the name of
>   R. Johanan: The Halachah follows R. Simeon b. Gamaliel. R. Johanan
>   further said: What is the reason of R. Simeon b. Gamaliel? Scripture
>   says, God enlarge Japheth, and he shall dwell in the tents of Shem;(1)
>   [this means] that the words of Japheth (2) shall be in the tents of
>   Shem.

and the words of Japheth in the tents of Shem take the form of a Sefer Torah written in Greek.

(1) The Jewish people are descended from Shem.

(2) Javan (Greece) is reckoned among the sons of Japheth in Gen. X, 2.

Comment: It seems totally wrong, it is only Kosher as Chumashim for kids, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108830/confusion-between-kosher-torah-scroll-in-greek-and-chumashim

Comment: That link doesn't exist...