# What is the status of the "minor tractates"?

Tags: history, talmud-gemara, authorship, oral-torah, authority

There is a collection of "[minor tractates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_tractate)" some of which contain material not found in other works of torah sh'baal peh (the oral law). What is the origin of these tractates? Who wrote/compiled them? What is their status in the hierarchy of torah sh'baal peh ie. do they outweigh a breita for example? Are they all considered authoritative?

Comment: Partial duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12880/3

Answer (score 1):

Semachos is reffured to in the Gemoro Moed kotton as aveil rabosi and is quoted numerous e.g moed kattan 13b and 24a תנא באבל רבתי  and brought many times in tur shulchan aruch times as being authoritive with regards to laws of mourning

Kalla is also quoted in kesubos in sugia of sheva brochos (kesubos 7b),and is enumerated amoungst authorotive masechtas a talmid chochom must know in kiddushin 49b and shabbos 114a. calla rabasi is an explanation of calla, and aggadic midrashim including chapter 6 pirkei avot.

sofrim is quoted by shulchan oruch as the source of taanis bchorim and various other dinim.

tzitzis, tefilin, geirim, sefer tora, kutim, and mezuza are all quotes from the gemoro brought together in one place.

avos de rabbi nosson ismainly aggadic teachings that are expanding on pirkei avos.

derech eretz rabba and zuto are about how one behaves at meals hosts, and other aggadic literature.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. מסכת כלה isn't Tractate Kallah but rather the tractate being learned at the current Yarchi Kallah study session. A Talmid Chakham needs to be proficient in the current topic of study. You can see this because the Talmud never uses the title מסכת X to refer to other Masekhtot.

Comment: "teach your tongue to say i don't know"(pirkei avos) rebbe,this is rashi in kiddushin ואפילו במסכת כלה - שאין עומק בה וברייתא היא וכך היא שנויה כלה בלא ברכה אסורה לבעלה כנדה not like you said

Comment: I did know that, and Rashi either was saying a drash or misunderstood. You too should be open to new ideas sometimes

Comment: judaism is based on masora, those who refuse to have the humility to accept what rishonim say should find a website with another religion and add their post scripts their

Comment: That's fine, I guess you should find another website since you are refusing to hear what Rishonim say. Do you know there are Rishonim aside from Rashi? Do Rambam, Ri, and Meiri not count as Rishonim? Just because Rashi came up with an interesting Drash doesn't make that Pshat or what the Gemara originally meant. Not every Girsa of the Talmud even has the word _Masekhet_ there. "teach your tongue to say i don't know" (pirkei avos)

Comment: i'm perfectly willing to accept that other rishonim argue as long a s you don't bring it as your opinion and show your sources as indicated in the guidelines of this website